# Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 6 Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql

I read a bunch of posts with similar problem but I am stuck.  In my table I have a column with datatype date.  I am trying to select all rows that are between these two dates that I'm going to pass in.  The column with date value something like this: 2012-03-26.  I have SQLEXPRESS version 10.0.5520.0

```
SELECT tblTransaction."Date"
FROM tblTransaction
where cast(tblTransaction."Date" as date) between cast('2012-03-00' as date) and cast('2012-03-28' as date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an invalid date

```
 cast('2012-03-00' as date)
```

Perhaps you meant

```
between cast('2012-03-01' as date) and cast('2012-03-28' as date)
```

Comment: sorry for the beginner error, this is what you get when you coding at night with coffee lol.

Answer (score 1):

First you don't need to cast string to data when you compare it with data type column. SQL Server will do it for you.
Second, use format 'yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss' if possible, which is always working in any culture.

```
tblTransaction."Date" BETWEEN '20120301' AND '20120328'
```

Note `'20120328'` equals to `'20120328 00:00:00'`. Use `20120328 23:59:59` if you use it against `datetime` column.